# Čech Cohomology with twisted coefficient: $H^1(\mathfrak{U}, \mathscr{F}) = 0$ on the circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory

I found this example in the book *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* of Bott and Tu :

> *Exercise 10.7 (Cohomology with twisted coefficients).* Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the presheaf on $S^1$ which associates to every open set the group $\mathbb{Z}$. We define the restriction homomorphism on the good cover $\mathfrak{U} = \{U_0, U_1, U_2\}$ (Figure 10.1) by:
>   $$\begin{align}
> \rho^0_{01} & = \rho^1_{01} = 1,\\
> \rho^1_{12} & = \rho^2_{12} = 1,\\
> \rho^2_{02} & = -1,\; \rho^0_{02} = 1,
> \end{align}$$
>   where $\rho^i_{ij}$ is the restriction from $U_i$ to $U_i \cap U_j$. Compute $H^*(\mathfrak{U}, \mathscr{F})$. (Cf. presheaf on an open cover, p. 142.)
>
> [image: Figure 10.1]

I found that $H^1(\mathfrak U, \mathcal F) = 0$. Is there any geometric interpretation of this result (and motivation for defining such restriction map)?

Comment: Don't you think the question looks better now? In the future please make an effort to transcribe the text, not just post a screenshot. It's better for sight-deficient people, it's better for searching the question, one can zoom and not get blurry text, copy the text...

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for taking time for editing !

Comment: But by the way, my question was not exactly to compute $H^*(\mathfrak U, \mathscr F)$ but to find a geometric explanation of the vanishing of this group

Comment: Well it's still present at the bottom, but you can add it to the title if you want. (In general finding a geometric interpretation for cohomology is not easy, IMO.)

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Maybe it's more easy to try to imagine the étalé space of $\mathscr F$ ?

Comment: The correct calculation should be $H^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549791/cohomology-with-twisted-coefficients/2551200

but I'd still be interested to hear a geometric interpretation of this.